# Querying sub documents in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am a beginner full stack web dev. and i am trying to make a movie rating website. so i have a user schema using mongoose and a ratings sub document in the schema.
The schema example:

```
const ratingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    url: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },
    comment: String
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    ratings: [ratingSchema]
})
```

an example of the schema in use will be:

```
const newuser = new User({
email: 'test1@a.com',
username: 'maintest',
password: 'aaaa',
ratings: [{
name: 'Avengers'
url: 'www.avengers.com',
rating: 5,
comment: 'Good Movie'
}]

})
```

given the example above:
i have a page that shows all the users ratings of each movie and i also have a search bar where i want to be able to search for a movie name and see the movie rating popup.
Basically my question is how do i query the database for all the ratings of every user and get each movie name out of the query. eg: i query the whole database and every user..because each user can rate the same movie and give it the same name.. and get the db of the users who rated the movie 'Avengers'.
Please if you need more information on this question, please dont hesitate to ask me!. Thanks

Comment: I think you can improve the db design by using reference to rating table and only storing ids in the user table. Then you can use populate to get the whole sub document. With mongoose query will be very simple like `User.findOne({"rating.name":"Avengers"})`

Comment: hello if i do this id have to refactor my whole website :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch), not tested it but you can try something like this with mongoose:

```
User.find().elemMatch('ratings', { name: 'Avengers'})
```

Comment: This worked!! to find each user with the name of the Movie. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

one way you could accomplish what you need is by doing:

```
db.getCollection("movie-ratings").aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$ratings" },
])
```

This will flat all your documents. Sample output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb059141d704dbea32156a9"), "email" : "test1@a.com", "username" : "maintest", "password" : "aaaa", "ratings" : { "name" : "Avengers", "url" : "www.avengers.com", "rating" : 5, "comment" : "Good Movie" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb059141d704dbea32156a9"), "email" : "test1@a.com", "username" : "maintest", "password" : "aaaa", "ratings" : { "name" : "Hulk", "url" : "www.avengers.com", "rating" : 2, "comment" : "Good Movie" } }
```

In addition, because you are inside an aggregate you can apply many different aggregate operators to it. For example, you could apply the match operator, to filter by a specific title:

```
db.getCollection("movie-ratings").aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$ratings" },
  { $match: { 'ratings.name': 'Avengers' } }
])
```

You can read more about the different operators here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

UPDATE: Using mongoose you could do something like this. Suppose you have a mongoose model called Ratings, then you could do:

```
const aggregate = Ratings.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$ratings" },
  { $match: { 'ratings.name': 'Avengers' } }
]);
```

You can find more info regarding aggregates with mongoose here:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate

I hope this can help you.

Comment: any way i can do this with mongoose?. thanks for the help

Comment: Yes not a problem, mongoose makes it really easy for you, check this out. Lets say you have a model that is called Ratings then you could do something like this: const  aggregate = Ratings.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$ratings" }
]);

Comment: hello again!, sorry but i still am not understanding how i can get an ouput of all the users with the rating name of avengers. Sorry for the disturbance